# Proof of the probabilistic definition of median

Tags: probability, probability-theory, median

> Definition: The median of a random variable $X$ is any real value $m$
>   s.t. $P(X \geq m)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \leq m)\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

This is a strong statement.

How do we prove this?

I always thought this statement is too strong and only believed that a median was a real value $m$ s.t. either $P(X \leq m) =1/2$ and $P(X>m)=\frac{1}{2}$ or it could be true that $P(X \geq m) =1/2$ and $P(X \leq m)=\frac{1}{2}$.

How do we prove the "$\geq \frac{1}{2}$"? part of the definition, which is stronger than just being equal to one-half?

Comment: You want to prove a definition?

Comment: It is a definition. One does not “prove” definitions—we state them!

Comment: As Bungo said, a definition is a definition, it can't be proved because there is nothing to be proven. This is just a fact. In any case, the definition for median would not work unless they both contained the option that $X$ be $m$. Consider the case that $X$ can be 1, 2, or 3 with equal probability. The median is obviously 2, but $P(X > 2) = 1/3$ and $P(X < 2) = 1/3$, so it wouldn't be the median. You actually need the exact inequality there for the definition to even work.

Comment: @JacobRaymond, assuming a uniform distribution, there's nothing false about $P(X>2)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $ P(X<2)=\frac{1}{3}$. $\forall X$ in the support. The only problem with this "definition" is that it doesn't restate itself as we don't know what $P(X=2)$ is, but obviously by definitions $P(X=2) =\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Exactly, but by the definition for median you provided, either of those facts would mean that 2 wasn't the median, though it clearly is. In order for 2 to be a median, you have that $P(X \ge 2) = 2/3$ and $P(X \le 2) = 2/3$. This proves, by definition, that 2 is the median of $X$. Neither of your definitions provided is strong enough to prove that 2 is the median

Comment: @JacobRaymond My definition leads to a contradiction? So therefore I didn't correctly define the median?

Comment: I posted a more complete response, but yes, essentially what I provided was a counterexample to your definitions of median.

Comment: @Germania assuming a uniform distribution for $X$, for a continuous RV on some interval say $(0,3)$ then we *do know* what $P(X=2)$ is—it’s equal to zero: $P(X=2)=0$. In fact all continuous RVs have that $P(X=a)=0$. Just a note since you wrote $P(X=2)=1/3$ and it is not clear to me if you were talking about a continuous RV or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, the direct answer to your question is that definitions are not proven, they are stated (as has been commented by two other people), so there is nothing to prove here about the definition of median.

Now, what you are really asking is why do we use this as the definition for median. While I do not personally know, I can prove that both of the definitions you provided are not equivalent characterizations of the median.

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes one of the values in $\{1,2,3\}$, each with equal probability. Then, by definition of a median, we can see that $2$ is the median of $X$, because $\mathbb{P}(X \ge 2) = 2/3 \ge 1/2$, and $\mathbb{P}(X \le 2) = 2/3 \ge 1/2$. So we know that $2$ is a median of $X$ **by definition**.

Now, in order for any alternate characterization for the median to be true, we must be able to show that $2$ is a median of $X$ in all cases at the very least. Any characterizations for the median that do not result in a median of $X$ being $2$ are definitely wrong, and any which do are only potentially correct.

Let's assume that $m$ is a median of $X$ when $\mathbb{P}(X \le m) = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X > m) = 1/2$. Since we know that $2$ is a median of $X$, then both of the equations must hold for $m = 2$. However, we can see that $\mathbb{P}(X \le m) = 2/3 \ne 1/2$, so this characterization for the median would imply that $2$ is not a median of $X$, but this contradicts the **proven** fact that it is, so this characterization can not be valid.

The same goes with the other characterization you provided.

Edit: Changed wording to say "a median" instead of "the median", since technically, there may be several medians in the case that the median is not a value that $X$ can take, though the argument still holds.